How to include jar file dependencies in target in final packaged jar file
I've been tasked with converting an Ant build to Maven. I'm not experienced with maven at all. I have for the most part been able to create the jar file "cem_rvtool.jar" that Ant was building, however, there are some missing dependencies in the jar file when I inspect it with a diff tool, Beyond Compare.
My project directory looks something like this:
project
 - src
 - target
   - jar files

I need those jar files to be packaged into the final jar, placed at the root directory. I've been doing a lot of research but haven't found a way to get this to work. Here is the pom file that I'm working with at the moment.
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Version-ID>${cem.build.version.id}</Build-Version-ID>
                            <Build-Timestamp>${timestamp}</Build-Timestamp>
                            <Rsrc-Main-Class>gov.cms.ccem.releasetool.RVToolLauncher</Rsrc-Main-Class>
                            <Rsrc-Class-Path>./ jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar ${jarfile.commons.beanutils} ${jarfile.commons.logging} ${jarfile.commons.lang} ${jarfile.commons.text} ${jarfile.slf4j.api} ${jarfile.log4j.api} ${jarfile.log4j.core} ${jarfile.log4j.slf4j.impl}</Rsrc-Class-Path>
                            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy file="target/cem_rvtool.jar" tofile="../../deploy/cem_rvtool.jar"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>project.properties</file>
                            <file>cem.properties</file>
                        </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>gov/cms/ccem/releasetool/*</include>
                        <include>resources/*</include>
                        <include>../*</include> <!-- Trying to capture jars -->
                        <include>../*.jar</include> <!-- Trying to capture jars -->
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>javax</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

Coincidentally, the jar files that I need to include are the dependencies listed above the plugins section (not shown). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

../.jar * I would doubt that is supported with some special kind of classloader that will load classes from "jars inside jars". I don't use the Assembly plugin but do use Shade, which allows one 'fat jar'

First recommendation is to upgrade the versions of the plugins you are using ... https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

You might need to take a look into maven-shade-plugin or maybe maven-assembly-plugin ... the configuration of the maven-jar-plugin looks wrong... etc...

I didn't realize it, but it turns out the jar files were being copied over, they just were being extracted so the class files were what was being included in the packaged jar file. An oversight on my part.
